# Eclipse code generation with papyrus

Tags: eclipse, plugins, uml, code-generation

When I try to install the code generation plug-in for Papyrus in Eclipse it gives me this error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Java code generator for
>   Papyrus 1.3.3.200911231214 (com.cea.papyrus.gen.java.feature.group
>   1.3.3.200911231214)   Missing requirement: Java code generator for Papyrus 1.3.3.200911231214 (com.cea.papyrus.gen.java.feature.group
>   1.3.3.200911231214) requires 'com.cea.papyrus.feature.feature.group 1.9.0' but it could not be found

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly ask the question on the Papyrus forum at: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/121/

Don't forget that Papyrus is an Eclipse plugins and should not be considered as an out of box modeling tools. I mean that you have many other plugins and you need to investigate and select the best of them. I know this is time consuming but this is the open source in which you are supposed to contribute yourself by adding code or at least testing all the plugins !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Papyrus feature and plugin structure but here my guess: Papyrus codegen (com.cea.papyrus.gen.java.feature.group) obviously requires the rest of Papyrus (com.cea.papyrus.feature.feature.group) which is not installed (or no matching version).
Solution: either install the correct papyrus version first or uninstall your papyrus packages and add the papyrus update site and let the codegen package choose the correct version.